# Invalid value 0 for Month field. while converting util.date to XMLgregoriandate?

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

I am converting java.util.Date to XMLGregorianDate.

When I print My util date on console, it displays:

> Date:  2011-01-25 20:33:46.54

But after conversion, when I try to use it, gives me following exception:
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Invalid value 0 for Month field.

```
Code for Date conversion is:
 DatatypeFactory df = null;

                    try {
                        df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
                    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
            gc.setTimeInMillis(account.getCreationDate().getTime());

method returns: df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
```

Also Interesting thing is that, when I display  util Date.getYear() and getMonth() methods (deprecated method used just to display date on console), output on console was:

> Year: 111 Month: 0

Why this is happening? Can anyone tell reason behind this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, printing out `date.getYear()` and `date.getMonth()` should indeed print 111 and 0, as `getYear()` returns the number of years since 1900, and `getMonth()` returns a 0-based month. A crazy API for sure, but that's the way it's documented.

Your conversion code isn't really clear though - you never *use* `df`, so what's the point of it? Likewise, I can't see any mention of `XMLGregorianDate` in your code... could you give a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem? Something that we can build and run?

As a side issue, in general I would *heartily* recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of java.util.{Date,Calendar} where possible. It may not help in this particular situation, but it avoids a lot of the poor design decisions of the built-in classes, and allows you to express exactly what you mean better (local dates, local times etc).

Comment: Sry, for incomplete code. I edited question and added some lines.

Comment: @Sagar: Again, a *complete* example would be more helpful. I'd like to be able to copy, paste, compile and run as a console application.

Answer (score 3):

The `XMLGregorianCalendar`, even if I don't see it in the example, uses a 1-based month number. Unlike the `java.util.Calendar` class, which uses a 0-bases month number.